# Check if Variable is empty. if so, set value. else, perform function

Tags: php

Can this be done?

I created a form which performs the function giveReaction. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is my code so far:

```
function giveReaction (){
    global $firstname;
    if ( empty($firstname) ) {
        $firstname = 'fill in your name, and get a response.';
        echo "$firstname";
    }
    else {
        $firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
        echo "hello, $firstname";
    }
}

echo "<form action=\"index.php?func_name=giveReaction()\" method=\"GET\">
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\">
        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"send\">
      </form>";

giveReaction();
```

Comment: I bet you're falling in the else all the time, right? Say what's the problem if not.

Comment: You never set `$firstname`. Take a look at some [php forms tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+forms+tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

There are a two immediate problems with your code:

1. You never define `$firstname` prior to checking it's empty
2. The action in your form does nothing, as you never handle `func_name` - this is not a built in feature of the language

To start fixing your code, you need to correctly handle the `firstname` input when the form has been submitted, for example:

```
$firstname = isset($_GET['firstname']) ? $_GET['firstname'] : '';
```

This ensures that `$firstname` will be the submitted value, or an empty string if it hasn't been provided yet.

So then you can define your function as follows:

```
function giveReaction (){
    $firstname = isset($_GET['firstname']) ? $_GET['firstname'] : '';
    if ( empty($firstname) ) {
        echo 'fill in your name, and get a response.';
    } else {
        echo "hello, $firstname";
    }
}
```

Secondly adjust your form to remove the unnecessary action, as by default forms will submit to the current page, and the `func_name` parameter isn't used.

```
echo "<form method=\"GET\">
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\">
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"send\">
  </form>";
```

Then you can finish as you have, by calling your function.

```
giveReaction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function can simply be:

```
function giveReaction() {
  $firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
  echo $firstname ? "hello, $firstname" : 'fill in your name, and get a response.';
}
```

There's no need to add it to the form.